# Android ListView Expand animation jumpy

Tags: android

I am making trying to make a listView item expand based on an button click.

So far everything is working and there are no errors. The problem is that the first time the animation jumps, the listItem jumps to expanded height, as opposed to smoothly sliding down. But after that the animation it works fine.

Also the animation only works when the expandedView is set to View.GONE in the adapter class before drawing.

Here is the animation class, it was taken from [here](https://github.com/Udinic/SmallExamples/tree/master/ExpandAnimationExample)

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
private View mAnimatedView;
private LayoutParams mViewLayoutParams;
private int mMarginStart, mMarginEnd;
private boolean mIsVisibleAfter = false;
private boolean mWasEndedAlready = false;

/**
 * Initialize the animation
 * @param view The layout we want to animate
 * @param duration The duration of the animation, in ms
 */
public ExpandAnimation(View view, int duration) {

    setDuration(duration);
    mAnimatedView = view;
    mViewLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

    // decide to show or hide the view
    mIsVisibleAfter = (view.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE);

    mMarginStart = mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin;
    mMarginEnd = (mMarginStart == 0 ? (0 - view.getHeight()) : 0);

    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public boolean willChangeBounds() {
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

    if (interpolatedTime < 1.0f) {

        // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

        // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        // Making sure we didn't run the ending before (it happens!)
    } else if (!mWasEndedAlready) {
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginEnd;
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();

        if (mIsVisibleAfter) {
            mAnimatedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        mWasEndedAlready = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems as though you should be animating the view's height rather than margins.

Comment: When trying to animate the height, its is always 0, so the animation never occurs

Comment: You can use `view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));` and `view.getMeasuredHeight();` to get the view's height before it is drawn.

Comment: I dont know how to use the View.measure.... but View.getMeasuredHeight() also returns 0, Note: Expanded view visibility is View.INVISIBLE

Comment: View.getMeasuredHeight does not work without a measure first.

Comment: Animating the height worked.